# Cisco 1760 T1 Setup

Tags: cisco, ios, t1

My 1760 has a WIC1-T1 card in Slot 0 and the slot 0 "OK" light is lit. When the router boots it shows that it sees the T1 card. I would like to configure my T1. I received the following details from my ISP:
* Removed IP's

```
IP Version: IPv4
Router Interface: edge1.mia1 -- t1-2/1/0:2:13 --
Switch Port:
Vlan:
WAN Network: 4.59.?.?/30
Level3 Side: 4.59.?.?
Customer Side: 4.59.?.?

Cust. LAN IPs: 4.59.?.?/27
```

The problem is that it is not listed under interfaces. I am a noob with IOS, please let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently it IS listed, I just need help configuring it:

Comment: Serial0/0 is administratively down, line protocol is down 
  Hardware is PQUICC with Fractional T1 CSU/DSU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conf t

ip default-gateway 4.59.?.?
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 4.59.?.?

int serial0/0
no shut
ip address 4.59.?.? 255.255.255.252
```

the first two 4.59.?.? should be replace with the "Level3 Side" IP and the last 4.59.?.? should be replaced with the "Customer Side" IP.

There may be some additional S0/0 configurations needed, especially encapsulation on a T1, but the above will get you closer than you are right now.

Comment: That is MUCH closer thanks. Here is the current status:

Comment: Serial0/0 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is PQUICC with Fractional T1 CSU/DSU
  Description: L3 T1
  Internet address is 4.59.?.?/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1544 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation PPP, loopback not set
  LCP Open
  Listen: CDPCP
  Open: IPCP

Comment: 5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     818 packets input, 36295 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     321 packets output, 11008 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     1 carrier transitions
     DCD=up  DSR=up  DTR=up  RTS=up  CTS=up

Comment: Now, if i set my ip to one in the Cust. LAN IPs range, and set the gateway to the Customer Side: 4.59.?.? it will not route. Any ideas?